# How to optimize a query to delete duplicates mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform

I have a table of 433,333 records in  a mySQL database on Google Cloud that looks something like this:

```
Album_ID | Track_Len | Track_Name                            | Ft_LName1 | Ft_FName1 | Ft_LName2 | Ft_FName2 | Ft_LName3 | Ft_FName3 | Row_Num |
+---------+-----------+---------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| N40781  |      5.19 | Tumbala (Da Lata Remix)               | NULL      | Novalima  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |       1 |
| N40781  |      5.01 | Ruperta (Zeb Remix)                   | NULL      | Novalima  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |       2 |
| N40781  |      6.35 | Coba Guarango (Toni Economides Remix) | NULL      | Novalima  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |       3 |
| B15033  |      6.02 | II-V-P                                | Quartet   | ARC       | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |       4 |
| N32395  |      4.47 | My Babe                               | Stigers   | Curtis    | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |       5 |
| N32395  |      5.13 | Thats All Right                       | Stigers   | Curtis    | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      | NULL      |       6 |
```

Note the primary key should be (Album_ID,Track_Name).
There are many duplicates so I am running the following to try and eliminate them:

```
delete from Track where (Album_ID, Track_Name, Row_Num) IN(
  select Album_ID, Track_Name, MAX(Row_Num)
  from (select Album_ID,Track_Name,Row_Num from Track) as x
  where (Album_ID, Track_Name) IN(
                  select Album_ID,Track_Name
                  from (select Album_ID,Track_Name from Track) as y
                  group by Album_ID, Track_Name
                  having count(*) > 1
                )
  group by Album_ID,Track_Name);
```

But this is taking far too long and does not delete all duplicates at once.
Any suggestions to optimize this query??

```
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Album_ID   | varchar(6)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Track_Len  | decimal(4,2)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Track_Name | varchar(100)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Ft_LName1  | varchar(40)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Ft_FName1  | varchar(40)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Ft_LName2  | varchar(40)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Ft_FName2  | varchar(40)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Ft_LName3  | varchar(40)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Ft_FName3  | varchar(40)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Row_Num    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please show us the full schema for `Track` and its indexes. And please show us [the `explain` output](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) for that query.

Comment: Because `Track_Name` can change, I'd suggest making the primary key a simple auto incremented integer and instead use a [unique index](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/) to enforce Album/Track uniqueness. The if you need to change the track name the reference will not break.

Comment: Agreed that a unique index would help. But I cannot add it while duplicate entries exist in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A traditional way of doing this in MySQL uses `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
delete t
    from Track t left join
         (select tt.Album_ID, tt.Track_Name, min(tt.row_num) as min_row_num
          from Track tt
          group by tt.Album_ID, tt.Track_Name
         ) tt
         on t.row_number = tt.min_row_num
    where tt.min_row_num is null;
```

This uses the fact the `id` is unique overall and probably the primary key.  You can also specify this as:

```
delete t
    from Track t join
         (select tt.Album_ID, tt.Track_Name, min(tt.row_num) as min_row_num
          from Track tt
          group by tt.Album_ID, tt.Track_Name
         ) tt
         on tt.Album_ID = t.Album_ID and
            tt.Track_Name = t.Track_Name and
            t.row_number > tt.min_row_num;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Album_ID` and `Track_Name` distinguish each row from another, try this with a self join:

```
delete t from Track t
inner join Track tt
where 
  tt.Album_ID = t.Album_ID and
  tt.Track_Name = t.Track_Name and
  tt.Row_Num < t.Row_Num
```

Comment: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause.

Comment: Do i need an Alias in the subquery?

Comment: No it's just Mysql which does not allow to specify the target table for update. If I have a way out I'll come back.

Comment: What happened??